# how to program SOAP-service without xmlns namespace

Tags: xml, web-services, delphi, soap

I am using DELPHI XE2 and have successfully published a SOAP-Service.
An example of the Client-Request looks as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://www.teccom-eu.net/wsdl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsdl:Ping/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is the SOAP-Response generated so far:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <PingResponse xmlns="http://www.teccom-eu.net/wsdl">
         <PingResult xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">My PingResult um 10.05.2017 15:39:21</PingResult>
      </PingResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What I would like to achieve is to have a SOAP-response without the xmlns for the PingResult, that line should look like this:

```
         <PingResult>My PingResult um 10.05.2017 15:39:21</PingResult>
```

I am looking for a solution by using some Register-function.
I tried already following, but no success:

```
InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(TecOpenMessagingSoap), 'Ping', 'PingResult', 'PingResult', '[Namespace="http://194"]', $FF); //IS_OPTN);
```

I know how to modify the SOAP-Response manually (kind of a hack), but I am hoping there is a more elegant way, especially when I will be adding more SoapActions.
Any help will be appreciated.

Added on May 17th 2017:
It would also be helpful to find more specific information on this registry procedure with more explanation on usable parameters:

```
InvRegistry.RegisterMethodInfo(TypeInfo(TecOpenMessagingSoap), 'Ping', '', '[ReturnName="PingResponse"]', IS_OPTN);
```

Comment: Hae you tried SoapUI with your service, to verify that your service implements SOAP correctly?

Comment: Yes, I am using SoapUI to test my service. The SOAP-response is received by SoapUI. I only want to modify/influence the format of the response.

Comment: just for information: I have to program the webservice for a fixed client; the client is not changeable from my side.